# Build python dict items with certain key name and value modification and consolidating all dict

Tags: python

I'm trying build python dict items with certain key name and value modification and consolidating all dict.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def Cftemplatebuild():
templateBucketName = {
    "NewBucketName" : {
        "Description" : "Bucket name",
        "Type" : "String",
        "Default": "bucketname",
        "AllowedPattern" : "[-a-z0-9\\-]*",
        "ConstraintDescription" : " Must be lowercase no spaces."
    }
}
i = 1
TemplateBucketName = {}
TemplateBucketPolicy = {}
bucketNameWithLink = [('TEST','TEST-LINK'),('PROD','PROD-LINK')]
for items in bucketNameWithLink: 
    print "ITEMS"
    print items[0]
    print items[1]
    print "BUCKET NAME CREATION"
    print 'actual', templateBucketName
    templateBucketNamecpy = templateBucketName.copy()
    print 'copy',templateBucketNamecpy
    templateBucketNamecpy['NewBucketName'+str(i)] = 
templateBucketNamecpy.pop('NewBucketName')
    print 'Modified key name', templateBucketNamecpy
    templateBucketNamecpy['NewBucketName'+str(i)]['Default'] = items[0]
    templateBucketNamecpy1 = templateBucketNamecpy.copy()
    print 'Modfied key value',templateBucketNamecpy
    print 'Copy Modified key value',templateBucketNamecpy1
    print "templateBucketName-1"
    print TemplateBucketName
    TemplateBucketName.update(templateBucketNamecpy1)
    print TemplateBucketName
    #templateBucketName['NewBucketName'] = 
templateBucketName.pop('NewBucketName'+str(i))
    print "templateBucketName-revert"
    #print TemplateBucketName
    print 'EnD actual',templateBucketName
    print "BUCKET NAME CREATION ENDS"
    i= i + 1
if __name__ == "__main__":
   Cftemplatebuild()
```

Expected output:

> {'NewBucketName1': {'Default': 'TEST', 'AllowedPattern': '[-a-z0-9\-]*', 'Type': 'String', 'Description': 'Bucket name', 'ConstraintDescription': ' Must be lowercase no spaces.'}, 'NewBucketName2': {'Default': 'PROD', 'AllowedPattern': '[-a-z0-9\-]*', 'Type': 'String', 'Description': 'Bucket name', 'ConstraintDescription': ' Must be lowercase no spaces.'}}

Actual output obtained:

> {'NewBucketName1': {'Default': 'PROD', 'AllowedPattern': '[-a-z0-9\-]*', 'Type': 'String', 'Description': 'Bucket name', 'ConstraintDescription': ' Must be lowercase no spaces.'}, 'NewBucketName2': {'Default': 'PROD', 'AllowedPattern': '[-a-z0-9\-]*', 'Type': 'String', 'Description': 'Bucket name', 'ConstraintDescription': ' Must be lowercase no spaces.'}}

Comment: Please correct your indentation

Comment: I haven't read your whole code but I bet there's a reference duplication problem. What if you `import deepcopy` and replace all your `some_dict.copy()` calls with `deepcopy.copy(some_dict)`?

Comment: @Kevin It should be `import copy` and `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: Thanks issue resolved with  copy.deepcopy()